# moment js: custom format string to day duration

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I'm have a rather wiered string with time. Something like this - `"2.23:59:59.99"`. That means that first number before dot is a day count (2 days) and other is a time count - 23 hours 59 minutes 59 seconds and 9900 - milliseconds (or maybe 99 milliseconds). So I need to convert it to decimal number, like `2.99`. How can I do it using moment.js ?

Comment: Where is your code that generates that string? And do you expect the output to be? `day.milliseconds`? Your question is unclear as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply [create](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) a moment duration from your `"2.23:59:59.99"` string

> As of **2.1.0**, moment supports parsing ASP.NET style time spans. The following formats are supported.
>
> The format is an hour, minute, second string separated by colons like `23:59:59`. The number of days can be prefixed with a dot separator like so `7.23:59:59`. Partial seconds are supported as well `23:59:59.999`.

and then get its values in days using [`asDays()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/days/)

> `moment.duration().asDays()` gets the length of the duration in days.

---

To get `"2.23:59:59.99"` back from `2.99`, you can create a duration using [`moment.duration(Number, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) and use [`format()`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#basics) method of [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) plug-in (using [precision](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#precision) parameter)

```js
// 2.23:59:59.99 to 2.99
const dur1 = moment.duration("2.23:59:59.99");
const durAsDays = dur1.asDays();
console.log(durAsDays);

// 2.99 to 2.23:59:59.99
const dur2 = moment.duration(durAsDays, 'days');
console.log(dur2.format("d.HH:mm:ss", 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/2.2.2/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @hofshteyn edited my answer to include `2.99` to `23:59:59.999` part

Answer (score 0):

```
moment.duration('2.23:59:59.99').asDays()
```

Refer to Moment JS [.asDays()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/days/) method